# Sqlite Syntax Error with Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Can anyone point me out where is the syntax error here?

For some reason I can't find it. I'm not sure if my approach is the correct one (I'm still testing it out).

Here's my code:

```
    final Cursor cursor;

    final String[] PROJECTION_SEARCH_FOR_CONTACT = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID,
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
        "name_raw_contact_id",
        Contacts.Data.DATA1 // Telephone number
    };

    // Search by Display Name
    if(where == 0)
    {
        cursor = contentResolver.query( Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                                        PROJECTION_SEARCH_FOR_CONTACT, 
                                        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '" + searchFor + "%' AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = " + Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, 
                                        null, 
                                        null);
    }

    // Search by Phone Number
    else if(where == 1)
    {
        cursor = contentResolver.query( Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                                        PROJECTION_SEARCH_FOR_CONTACT, 
                                        Contacts.Data.DATA1+ " LIKE '" + searchFor + "%' AND " + Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " = " + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, 
                                        null, 
                                        null);
    }

    // Search by Email
    else 
    {
        cursor = contentResolver.query( Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                                        PROJECTION_SEARCH_FOR_CONTACT, 
                                        Contacts.Data.DATA1+ " LIKE '" + searchFor + "%' AND " + Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " = " + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, 
                                        null, 
                                        null);
    }
```

Here are the exception errors.

**For `where == 0` :**

```
03-05 00:31:06.473: E/SQLiteLog(2012): (1) near ".": syntax error
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012): Writing exception to parcel
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name, photo_id, name_raw_contact_id, data1 FROM view_data data LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT data_usage_stat.data_id, SUM(data_usage_stat.times_used) as times_used, MAX(data_usage_stat.last_time_used) as last_time_used FROM data_usage_stat GROUP BY data_id) as data_usage_stat ON (data_usage_stat.data_id=data._id) WHERE (1) AND ((display_name LIKE 'c%' AND mimetype = vnd.android.cursor.item/contact))
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.validateQuerySql(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:412)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:389)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:6438)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.queryLocal(ContactsProvider2.java:6386)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:4999)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
03-05 00:31:06.477: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

**For `where == 1` :**

```
03-05 00:32:21.922: E/SQLiteLog(2012): (1) near ".": syntax error
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012): Writing exception to parcel
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name, photo_id, name_raw_contact_id, data1 FROM view_data data LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT data_usage_stat.data_id, SUM(data_usage_stat.times_used) as times_used, MAX(data_usage_stat.last_time_used) as last_time_used FROM data_usage_stat GROUP BY data_id) as data_usage_stat ON (data_usage_stat.data_id=data._id) WHERE (1) AND ((data1 LIKE 'c%' AND mimetype = vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2))
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.validateQuerySql(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:412)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:389)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:6438)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.queryLocal(ContactsProvider2.java:6386)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:4999)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
03-05 00:32:21.938: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

**For `where == 2` :**

```
03-05 00:33:13.844: E/SQLiteLog(2012): (1) near ".": syntax error
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012): Writing exception to parcel
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name, photo_id, name_raw_contact_id, data1 FROM view_data data LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT data_usage_stat.data_id, SUM(data_usage_stat.times_used) as times_used, MAX(data_usage_stat.last_time_used) as last_time_used FROM data_usage_stat GROUP BY data_id) as data_usage_stat ON (data_usage_stat.data_id=data._id) WHERE (1) AND ((data1 LIKE 'c%' AND mimetype = vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2))
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.validateQuerySql(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:412)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:389)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:6438)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.queryLocal(ContactsProvider2.java:6386)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:4999)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
03-05 00:33:13.852: E/DatabaseUtils(2012):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
... mimetype = vnd.android.cursor.item/contact
```

You need to put the string literals in `''` single quotes. For example,

```
... Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"
```

and similarly for the other cases.

Comment: Thanks, that's what happens when you (me, in this case) wants to code it fast for testing purposes. So solution is to use the selection field on the cursor. Like this: `cursor = contentResolver.query( Data.CONTENT_URI, 
           PROJECTION_SEARCH_FOR_CONTACT, 
           Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '" + searchFor + "%' AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?", 
           new String[]{Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, 
           null);`

Comment: Yes, that will also work. Using `?` placeholders for literals is a good habit, even if in this case there's no direct benefit (nor harm).